# GUI like the Visual Studio Installer one in JAVA

Tags: java, visual-studio, user-interface, microsoft-metro, border

my question is: There is a way to make GUI in Java like the one from Visual Studio Installer? Like this: [VS GUI STYLE](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-40-70-metablogapi/5545.image_5F00_75682A3C.png)

Being more detailed... a GUI without the regular windows borders, with plain color, without the "3D" feel. Well, the linked image summarize the idea well.

Thanks for the attention and sorry for my poor english =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking Swing, then yes.. use:

setUndecorated(true);

on your JFrame.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29

Comment: Thank you! JavaFX is able to do the same thing?? Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Yup. new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)

Check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html